# Video.js reuse ID - destroy()

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I'm retrieving my video source using ajax. All works fine unless I try to retrieve and play the same video twice.

http://jsfiddle.net/w3JPB/3/

You will notice that the second time you click "add" video.js doesn't work and the plain default html5 video player is shown.

It seems like I need to destroy the old video object but method described [here](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/861-how-to-destroy-a-video-js-object) gives me an error saying "object has no method destroy".

`_V_('video1').destroy()`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Latest video.js version exposes `dispose` method instead. Check your [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/w3JPB/10/). Working fine for me.